# BCS search issue in SharePoint 2016 - Error while crawling LOB contents

Tags: enterprise-search, bcs, 2016

We have configured BCS search in SharePoint 2016. We have got "Error while crawling LOB contents" while crawling BCS content source in search service application.

```
**Error** 
Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Error caused by exception: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException An error occurred. Administrators, see the server log for more information.; SearchID = 06BC52B9-5CE6-4AD8-82F4-D86E1EB22DE3 )
We have checked in ULS log, found below exception

SPSecurityContext: Request for security token failed with exception: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  <head>  <title>IIS 8.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error</title>  <style type="text/css">  <!--  body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}  code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} ... b5236d91-f4bb-4bd1-8d4f-651ee62f59d7
config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}  pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}  ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;}  ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;}  fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;}  .summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;}  legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}  legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px;  font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;}  a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;}  a:hover{text-decoration:none;}  h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}  h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Htt... b5236d91-f4bb-4bd1-8d4f-651ee62f59d7
pChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request... b5236d91-f4bb-4bd1-8d4f-651ee62f59d7
(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChanne... b5236d91-f4bb-4bd1-8d4f-651ee62f59d7
l.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo, SPRequestSecurityTokenProperties properties) b5236d91-f4bb-4bd1-8d4f-651ee62f59d7
```

I have followed below steps to configure BCS in SharePoint 2016
Created BCS in SharePoint 2016. 
Created external content type using SharePoint designer. Create external list using same content type. The external list is working fine.
Created content source using external content type, the crawling of content source throws above error.
Please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you configure read permissions for the crawling account on the BCS service application?

Comment: yes,crawling account(farm account) having full permission.

Comment: Two things, the crawl account should never be the Farm account. Second, the crawl account only needs EXECUTE on the Content Type. Have you tested the permissions by browsing to the external list as the crawl account?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the BCS Profile page is configured or not . (BCS Profile Page is needed for search)
2. change the authentication model in SharePoint designer (like BDC )